# Serverless Laravel deploy issue

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, serverless, bref

I have created my larvel application and try to deploy it on AWS lambda so I have used bref & serverless framework for that , but website link give me blank page , and when I have back to cloudwatch for see the logs and this what exists [cloudwatch logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEKZA.png)

and here is my serverless.yml

```
    service: app

provider:
    name: aws
    region: us-east-1
    runtime: provided

plugins:
    - ./vendor/bref/bref

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - public/storage
    - resources/assets/**
    - storage/**
    - tests/**

functions:
    website:
        handler: public/index.php
        timeout: 28 # in seconds (API Gateway has a timeout of 29 seconds)
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-73-fpm}
        events:
            -   http: 'ANY /'
            -   http: 'ANY /{proxy+}'
    artisan:
        handler: artisan
        timeout: 120 # in seconds
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-73} # PHP
            - ${bref:layer.console} # The "console" layer
```

I have no idea where to look , some body help me please